# Stored Procedure WHERE OR HAVING Does Not Work

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, having-clause

In the below procedure,

It gives error ([Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function) when I use WHERE statements and it gives another error ([Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'roomid' in 'having clause') when I use HAVING statements instead of WHERE, although I have the roomid column defined in the table.

Does anybody have an idea on how can I fix this issue? The code was working perfectly when I tried under another mySQL version I guess.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `findAVG`//
CREATE DEFINER=`kamer`@`%` PROCEDURE `findAVG`(IN rid INT, startDate DATETIME, OUT Score DOUBLE)
BEGIN        
    DECLARE finishDate DATETIME; 
    DECLARE DateIterator DATETIME;
    DECLARE avgPrice DOUBLE;
    SET avgPrice = 0;
    SET Score = 0;
    SELECT price into Score 
    FROM bookings 
    WHERE roomid = rid 
    ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( bookings.date, startDate)) LIMIT 1;

    IF (Score = 0) THEN 
        SET DateIterator = startDate;
        SET finishDATE = DATE_ADD(startDate,  INTERVAL 30 DAY); 
        WHILE DateIterator <=  finishDate DO
            SELECT price 
            INTO avgPrice 
            FROM prices 
            WHERE roomid = rid 
            AND date = DateIterator 
            ORDER BY DATEDIFF(startDate, prices.timestamp) LIMIT 1;   

            SET DateIterator = DATE_ADD(DateIterator,  INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        END WHILE;
        SET Score = AVG(avgPrice);
    END IF;

    UPDATE bookings SET price=Score WHERE roomid= rid AND date=startDate;
END
```

Comment: What are you expecting `AVG(avgPrice)` to give you?

Comment: Average prices of 30 subsequent days of given roomid=rid, starting from the startDate. However, as I said the procedure was working, just due to changing mySQL function. It gave the above error, invalid use of group function. Then, when I changed to HAVING, it gave another error.

Comment: Note: There are multiple prices of each day, so It also takes the most recent one before taking the average, according to startDate.

Comment: Let's say the value of avgPrice is 3.14 (after all, it is defined as a double); the average of the set { 3.14 } is 3.14 - you may want to move the aggregation into the query

Comment: Dear Rowland, thank you for trying to help, but I did not understand what is wrong with this. I am unable to move the aggregation to the query as I limit. Even if I do, I do not think this would remove errors I got. I will try right now anyways. Do you have any solution for the errors I get? due to HAVING or WHERE statements.

Comment: I tried what you have recommended still says [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'roomid' in 'having clause'.

Comment: HAVING AND WHERE are not independent statements. They are clauses of data modification statements like SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE.  In your code above, you are calling AVG(avgPrice) as part of a simple SET statement, which is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you very much! Fixed when I did avgPrice/30. However, prices on some dates may be missing and may return NULL. How can I take the average on avgPrice, instead of directly diving it to a constant number?

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid use of group function" mean you've used a column in the group by function that does not appear in the select clause or the inverse.

i.e. :

```
SELECT A,B,C,COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY A,B,C
```

Grouping is done on the 3 firts's columns and the count is done on each line where A,B and C are similar.

For example, if you try to pass "GROUP BY A,B" SQL wont know what to do with C column...

For HAVING problem, it seem to me the HAVING clause is applicated after the select have been done.
So if you're using a column that doesn't appear in the SELECT clause, then it raise an error.

Comment: Actually, MySql does allow `SELECT A,B,C,COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY A` but the values for `B` and `C` are indeterminate